# How to find values that generate a particular boolean expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, boolean-algebra, boolean

On question 1 of our homework we are asked to find which values of the boolean variables equate to the resulting boolean expression. I tried finding resources on how to complete this but I came up short. If anybody is able to help me through this problem I’d greatly appreciate it!

```
For which values of the boolean variables x, y, and z does
    a) x + y + z = xyz

    b) x(y + z) = x + yz

    c) x’y’z’ = x + y + z
```

Me and my friend came up with these answers:

```
a) x=y=z = 1
b) x = 0, y = 1, z = 0 or 1
c) x=y=z = 0
```

Comment: Truth tables? The answer for c) is wrong, b.t.w.: if all three variables are zeroes, the L.H.S. is one, whereas the R.H.S. is zero.

Comment: Trick for c): since the L.H.S. is a product, negate it twice and revert the product to sums with the inner negation: $x’y’z’=(x’y’z’)’’=(x’’+y’’+z’’)’=(x+y+z)’$. Equating it to the R.H.S. gives you something of the form $z’=z$, which **has no solutions.**

Comment: Seriously? There are only 8 possible assignments to consider. Do the work.